# How to create a thumbnail from a several sizes of images?

Tags: html, css, jsp

I got a web page in JSP, the page is showing several images which being uploaded from the user in any size, the goal is to show each image as a thumbnail.

Currently I made a style to `img` tag with: `height="20%" width="auto"` and it's good enough for medium and large images, but when the image is small it makes it very small.

How can I make the images in the same size?

Comment: set css minwidth property for img to your desired minimum width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height` to an absolute value. For example:

```
<img height="200px" width="auto">
```